# How do I remove GPG private keys from memory?

Tags: security, gnupg

When I do the following:

```
gpg --decrypt somefile.pgp
```

I see a graphical dialog come up asking me for the passphrase for my private GPG key.

After that, subsequent runs don't require a passphrase, as they seemingly use the GPG key from an in-memory GPG agent.

How do I clear out all keys of that GPG agent? I don't like them hanging around in memory uselessly.

Comment: Elementary OS is NOT a supported derivative of Ubuntu, and is not supported on this site.  Please use [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) for Elementary OS questions.   (To all reviewers/close voters: This comment and related close vote is based on [the OP's comment on the answer below](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481663/how-do-i-remove-gpg-private-keys-from-memory#comment641530_481668).)

Comment: That's alright, can you please migrate it to Unix & Linux?

Comment: we usually don't migrate questions to there, you might be better off going and posting there yourself...

Answer (score 3):

`man gpg-agent` gives you:

```
   --default-cache-ttl n
          Set the time a cache entry is valid to n seconds.  The default is 600 seconds.
```

Either modify the way you start gpg-agent and add this parameter with a shorter time-to-live or don't start gpg-agent at all.

**Edit**

You need to figure out which exactly program is asking you for the passphrase. So far it become clear that it is not gpg-agent and not seahorse.

With the window open run `wmctrl -lp | grep "The Window Title, Case Sensitive"`. You should see a row like:

```
0x03e0000c  0 2580   <your_host_name>  The Window Title
```

The 3-rd number is the process id. Run `cat /proc/2580/cmdline` (replacing 2580 with the actual process id) and you will see the program file of the thing that is asking you for your password, along with any parameters. Then you can look that one up and see what you could do about it. Uninstalling it is certainly an option.

Comment: This isn't installed on my machine. Do I need to install it to modify the agent?

Comment: I thought you mentioned GPG agent in your question. Nevermind, do not install it since you obviously do not want its services. If it is not gpg-agent then you are most likely dealing with a program named `seahorse` - the Gnome GUI frontent to GnuPG. Start program `Password and Keys` from the dash (or `seahorse` from a terminal) and see if you can configure your keys there.

Comment: Interesting, `seahorse` also isn't installed. Perhaps it's because I'm running elementary Luna?

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay Elementary OS is NOT a supported derivative of Ubuntu, and is not supported on this site.  Please use [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) for Elementary OS questions.